# Ctrl+A (select all) does not work in some textboxes throughout Windows XP

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, selection

I'm having a hard time with my Windows XP. Ctrl+A combination does not select all text in some textboxes throughout whole system. For instance it does not work in start->Run command window nor does it work in my own WinForms application that I've developed under .NET 3.5 framework.

On the other hand CTRL+A does work in Firefox or IE8 location bar.

What can be the source of that problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wherever the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+A shortcut does not work you can use <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+< key or <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>HOME</kbd> keys to select all. It works everywhere in the system.

Answer (score 4):

Strictly speak there is no problem here to try and find the source of.

As a shortcut, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> = `Select All` is *not* something implemented by Windows.

It will only work in those programs that implement this shortcut themselves, not universally across the system.

Comment: I agree that it is not implemented in XP or Server 2003, but it is implemented in Windows 7 and Server 2008 (and probably Vista), at least for the Run box. So Michael Lucas, your system does not technically have a problem...it just lacks a feature.